# How can I begin with Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm beginner for the GUI programing using Tkinter, so who can tell me some useful sample codes which contains some useful codes.

Answer (score 8):

I learned using [<strike>this pdf</strike>](http://woldlab.caltech.edu/bioinformatics/references/tkinter.pdf).

Edit:  Per MatrixFrog's comment, use [this link](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/lang/python/tkinter.pdf) for the latest version.

Comment: Same one I was going to recommend, but since it's from "New Mexico Tech Computer Center" I would assume this link is a newer version: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/lang/python/tkinter.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I found [Thinking in Tkinter](http://www.ferg.org/thinking_in_tkinter/index.html) very helpful for getting my head around the concepts of GUI programming (notably, packing widgets inside other widgets, and binding callbacks to events).

Answer (score 3):

I used Manning's book on Tkinter, as someone else mentioned. The tutorials are very thorough, and you quickly get into the habit of thinking like a GUI coder. The New Mexico Tech worksheet is useful as a reference, but a bit too clumsy for a first resource.

Comment: Manning Book is very outdated and it largely talks about PMW megawidget not to forget that it does not mention anything about ttk widgets which is a vast improvement on old Tkinter. A good and updated book is Tkinter GUI Application Development Hotshot by Packt Publishers

Answer (score 2):

Mark Lutz's tome *Programming Python* deals at length with Tkinter. The *Introduction to Tkinter* ( effbot.org) and *Tkinter reference: a GUI for Python* (John Shipman, New Mexico Tech) are good summaries of the major features. I have read that the Tk/Tcl manual is a good reference but that might be for later.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used: [Pythonware -- An introduction to TKinter](http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/).

I quickly switched to [PyQT](http://www.qtrac.eu/pyqtbook.html), though :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are several [video series](http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/series?name=pythonShawnTkinterSeries) on building python GUIs that got me started

Comment: Those seem to have nothing to do with Tkinter. Did you post the wrong link, or are you trying to steer people away from Tkinter?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley sorry about that I did post the wrong link

Answer (score 1):

This is a website that taught me almost everything i know in tkinter:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you learn best from video, Charlie, I recommend http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=pythonShawnTkinter1&fromSeriesID=58 ; if from books, http://www.manning.com/grayson/ .  For a free online tutorial, I second bedwyr's advice -- and I *especially* second his (implicit;-) advice to use PyQt instead.  (A web search for pyqt tutorial shows many pointers).

Comment: Could you expand on why you prefer PyQt to Tkinter?

Answer (score 0):

You have the source for idle.  That shows useful tkinter code.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across http://www.shido.info/py/python6_e.html which looks very handy